# Django CSV upload UploadForm to database Clean

Tags: django, csv, modelform, stringio, django-uploads

i would like to store the data from my uploaded CSV file, called

> data_file

I cant loop over the rows by column name in my csv file. 
I get Encoding errors(UTF, ASCII), also when i use IO String. 
I am new to django so i dont know what i do wrong.

I tried to do this in my view with:

```
def upload(request): 
 form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
   if form.is_valid():
           f = io.TextIOWrapper(form.cleaned_data['data_file'].file, enconding='utf-8')
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for column in reader:
print(column['Customer Name'])
```

the error i get is:

> utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: invalid continuation byte

Changed it to 'latin-1' (see comments)
Gives error

> line contains NULL byte

I dont have NULL values in my CSV file

Comment: I would guess you have the wrong encoding. Could you try changing `'utf-8'` to `'latin-1'`?

Comment: Thank you, it worrks i think.. I got a new error line contains NULL byte. My file has no null value's.

Comment: a NULL byte does not mean a null value in your csv, but rather a certain type of unencodable byte in your CSV file. Carefully check the input on the line number specified.

Comment: Thank you problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
f.readline()
```

the first line was empty